# Model not overridden

Tags: extensions, overrides, model, payment-methods

I am trying to below model in my extension. But unfortunately it is not overridden.
Please check class path which I want to overwrite :

Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung_Model_Service_Communication
{
}

For above model I tried below code in my extension's config.xml,

```
<global>
<models>
    <pnsofortueberweisung>
        <rewrite>      
        <service_communication>Mycompany_Myextension_Model_Service_Communication</service_communication>
        </rewrite>
    </pnsofortueberweisung>
</models>
</global>
```

I also tried

```
<paymentnetwork_pnsofortueberweisung>
```

instead of

```
<pnsofortueberweisung>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

config.xml important code of "Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung"

```
 <config>
 <global>
    <models>
        <sofort>
         <class>Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung_Model</class>
        </sofort>
    </models>
   <events>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
            <observers>
                <paymentnetwork_pnsofortueberweisung_observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>refillBasket</method>
                </paymentnetwork_pnsofortueberweisung_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_success>
    </events>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pisofort>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
             <module>Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung</module>
                <frontName>pisofort</frontName>
            </args>
        </pisofort>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you add `Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung` module `config.xml` ? as well in which codePool it is in? same for your extension?

Comment: I have added code of config.xml. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot rewrite a rewrite. What you have to do is rewrite the original Magento model with yours and then extend the other rewrite. Also make sure, your module `<depends>` on the other one so that your rewrite takes precedence.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<global>
<models>
    <sofort>
        <rewrite>      
        <service_communication>Mycompany_Myextension_Model_Service_Communication</service_communication>
        </rewrite>
    </sofort>
</models>
</global>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: i also tried it but it is not working for me.

Comment: On which codePool of this both extensions are? Also check is there compilation or cache enabled? Disable them and check

Comment: Paymentnetwork_Pnsofortueberweisung extension is in community and our extension is in local. compilation and cache are disabled already. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23804315/5668224